# How to search in a list across more elements unified in a single string and return the position?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have a list like the following:

```py
['56', '33 f6', '39 74 24 0c', '57', '74 07', '68 1c e0 40 00', 'eb 05', '68 18 e0 40 00', '68 10 e0 40 00', 'ff 15 18 81 40 00', '8b f8', '59', '3b fe', '59', '75 04', '33 c0']
```

Let's say I want to search for a sequence as:

`'33 f6 39 74 24 0c 57 74'` and then know which elements of the list are covered. In this case it would be position 2,3,4,5.

I thought of unifying the list in one string and do the search through `find()`. But I wouldn't know how to go forward.

Is there a better way to do this in Python?

EDIT: The solution accepted worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortest version I could come up with:

```
arr = ['56', '33 f6', '39 74 24 0c', '57', '74 07', '68 1c e0 40 00', 'eb 05', '68 18 e0 40 00', '68 10 e0 40 00', 'ff 15 18 81 40 00', '8b f8', '59', '3b fe', '59', '75 04', '33 c0']
search_term = '33 f6 39 74 24 0c 57 74'
joined = ' '.join(arr)
search_index = joined.find(search_term)
contained_indices = []
counter = 0
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if counter >= search_index and counter <= search_index + len(search_term):
        contained_indices.append(i)
    if counter >= search_index + len(search_term):
        break
    counter += len(arr[i])+1

print(contained_indices)
```

Note that it uses 0-based indexing and it will probably fail if you do not have the neat structure in your current array anymore.